# How do I change this fill gradient from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<svg width="100" height="50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style type="text/css">
        rect{fill:url(#MyGradient)}
      </style>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
          <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F60" />
          <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FF6" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>

      <rect width="100" height="50">
</svg>
```

I want #F60 to be the bottom and #FF6 to be the top and i dont want to rotate it ..

Comment: I never worked with svg but, can't you just switch the 'stop' lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` to specify direction of `linearGradient` ([w3c spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradients)):

```css
rect {
  fill: url(#MyGradient);
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="MyGradient" x1="100%" y1="100%">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F60" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FF6" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>       
  <rect width="100" height="50" />
</svg>
```